# Navigation Drawer item Click not Works.followed Questions

Tags: android, xml, menu, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I have used navigation drawer in the code.When clicking items noting happens.Tried various things from Stackoverflow and net.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;


 public class searchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
  public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
  public ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle=new 
    ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open_drawer,R.string.close_drawer);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView=(NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.bringToFront();
    drawerLayout.requestLayout();
    }
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
   {

     DrawerLayout drawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
     {
         drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
     }
     else {
         drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
     }

     if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
         return true;
     }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
     Toast toast=Toast.makeText(searchActivity.this,"On navigation item 
      selected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     toast.show();
     DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
     return true;
   }
   }
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
tools:context=".searchActivity">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/search_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFEB3B"
    android:text="@string/add"
    android:textColor="#BF360C"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/food_listview"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.413"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/search_box"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.552" />

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/search_box"
    android:layout_width="289dp"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:hint="@string/type_food"
    android:textColorHint="#757575"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/food_listview"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/search_button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.432"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/food_listview"
    android:layout_width="357dp"
    android:layout_height="496dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As suggested in many have put the navigationView in the last of the xml also. still does not help. Made many changes. as suggested in many have put the navigationView in the last of the xml also. still does not help.

Comment: someone please reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       Check this answer:
    
    search_activity.xml
        
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        
            <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                tools:openDrawer="start">
        
                <include
                    layout="@layout/activity_main"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        
                <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
                    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_240sdp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                    android:background="@color/white_color"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_drawer"
                    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>
        
            </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
        
        </LinearLayout>
    
  SearchActivity.java
    
    public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
    
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.search_activity);
    
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
            toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    
     drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            toggle.syncState();
            toggle.getDrawerArrowDrawable().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white_color));
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
            navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    }

  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent home = new Intent(SearchActivity.this, Your_Acivity.class); //here place your Activity Class
                startActivity(home);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_car_info:
                Intent car_info = new Intent(SearchActivity.this,Your_Activity.class);  //here place your Activity Class
                startActivity(car_info);
                break;
          
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything works except item click on nav bar does not work.i.e onNaviagtionItemClicked(..) never gets called

Comment: check my answer  inside @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) { switch (menuItem.getItemId()) } like this implement.

Comment: tried.doesnt helps

Comment: could you connect me on remote!

Comment: yeah sure. how to?

Comment: can you share your mail?

Comment: check my profile where i mention my email id.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above.I have called setContentView() in onCreate() as well as onResume() .I removed the latter. and it worked fine.